# how do i use should with mocha and mongoose?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I keep getting an error in the save() method when I run the test.

```
var User = require('../../models/user')
, should = require('should');

describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User({
        username    : 'User1'
        , email     : 'user1@example.com'
        , password  : 'foo'
      });
      user.save(function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;

        it('should have a username', function(done){
          user.should.have.property('username', 'User1');
          done();
        });
      });
    })
  })

})
```

here is the error:

```
$ mocha test/unit/user.js

  ․

  ✖ 1 of 1 test failed:

  1) User #save() should save without error:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:1
61:14)
      at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

Comment: How we can set `username` property from real function so that we get username property in `user.should.have.property('username', 'User1');`? Can we send as `res.send({username: 'User1'})` or  `res.render('home', {username: 'User1'})` in real function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can nest describes but not it tests. Each test is meant to be stand alone so when you are looking through your results you can see where it is failing - on the save or not having the username property. For example in your code above there is no way for it to fail the 'should save without error' test as there is no done(). Which is also the reason the code above is timing out: mocha cannot find the done() for the 'should save without error' test.

Being able to nest describes is very powerful though. Within each describe you can have a before, beforeEach, after and afterEach statement. With these you can achieve the nesting that you are attempting above. See the mocha docs for more information if you want to read up on these statements.

The way I would write what you are trying to achieve is as follows:

```
var User = require('../../models/user')
    , should = require('should')
    // this allows you to access fakeUser from each test
    , fakeUser;

describe('User', function(){
  beforeEach(function(done){
    fakeUser = {
      username    : 'User1'
      , email     : 'user1@example.com'
      , password  : 'foo'
    }
    // this cleans out your database before each test
    User.remove(done);
  });

  describe('#save()', function(){
    var user;
    // you can use beforeEach in each nested describe
    beforeEach(function(done){
      user = new User(fakeUser);
      done();
    }

    // you are testing for errors when checking for properties
    // no need for explicit save test
    it('should have username property', function(done){
      user.save(function(err, user){
        // dont do this: if (err) throw err; - use a test
        should.not.exist(err);
        user.should.have.property('username', 'User1');
        done();
      });
    });

    // now try a negative test
    it('should not save if username is not present', function(done){
      user.username = '';
      user.save(function(err, user){
        should.exist(err);
        should.not.exist(user.username);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: When I run this test I get: `  it('should have username property', function(done){
  ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` it doesn't like "it("
`

Comment: If I add another describe as a 2nd child of the first describe, the User.rmeove() doesn't have any effect.

Comment: How we can set `username` property from real function so that we get username property in `user.should.have.property('username', 'User1');`? Can we send as `res.send({username: 'User1'})` or  `res.render('home', {username: 'User1'})` in real function?

Comment: @chovy would you mind sharing how you solved the `ìt` bug please ?

Comment: @edelans i don't recall, i think maybe it was a cut-n-paste error, but here's what I am using now: https://gist.github.com/chovy/e637f4f84436cfafa0ce

Comment: Thanks for your sample. This was really helpful for me as I'm just learning how to use Mocha. I was wondering if these kind of tests have to go down all the way to the database and actually write the object to the database. All I wanna test is if the validation in mongoose works.